# Let Nagios check not-allways-on workstations

Tags: nagios

we try to monitor the file age on some of our workstations. Works fine with NSClient++ - but we do not want to get any CRITICALs when the computer is shut down.

For the host, we do have a dummy check, returning OK every check. But when the workstation is offline, the check for the file age fails with a 'connection refused'.

Do you have any hints to avoid those CRITICALs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the service is associated with the host(name), if the check-host-alive (or whatever you've configured) test fails, the service alerts won't be sent.  Remember to add a margin of error in your max_checks to account for a situation where the computer is shutting down, but still responding to pings (or whatever you use for check-host-alive).

Alternately, if your file-age-checker only issues WARNINGs, not CRITICALs, where WARNINGs are file-age-out-of-bounds errors, while CRITICALs are host-unreachable errors, just mask off the CRITICALs:

```
service_notification_options w,u,r
```

That said, what you should really do, if that's your goal, is to rewrite the plugin to return UNKNOWN for that circumstance, in which case it'd be:

```
service_notification_options c,w,r
```

Comment: spot on! this is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Are the workstations switched off during predictable times?  i.e, are they only going to be on from 9am-5pm, or something similar?  If so, you can define a time period in Nagios and apply it to the workstations; then they'll only get checked within that time period.

Comment: Yes and no. Normally, they're switched off from 4pm until 8am. But in the holiday season, some machines are switched off for several weeks. So, the time periods would not help.

Comment: I have the same problem with network printers; for holidays, I usually just give them all an appropriately-size period of downtime.

Comment: Yep, but I do not want to set downtimes for about 300 workstations ;)

Comment: In that case, you probably want to investigate "hostgroups".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the -u option in check_nrpe?